# I am reading line by line from a json file and appending the data to a list, but it is only appending the last line in the list

Tags: python, json, list

I'm reading from a JSON file which is very large, I am using json.loads method to read each line from the JSON file, yet it stores only the data of the last line in the list.

When I was loading the whole JSON file and then accessing the data, it was working fine but when working line by line it isn't working properly.

```py
with open('tinyTwitter(3).json','r',encoding = 'utf-8',errors='ignored') as f:
    next(f)    
    for line in f:

        try:
            data =(json.loads(line))


        except:
            continue
        lst.append(data)
```

It should store all the values in the lst list.

Comment: What does your file look like?

Comment: the first line is `{"total_rows":3877777,"offset":805584,"rows":[`


the second line is `{"id":"570379215192727552","key":["r1r01cdn8nb4",2015,2,25],"value":{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[144.92340088,-37.95935781]},"properties":`

Comment: And the rest? Is your file a complete JSON or is each line in the file a json?

Comment: Put a log in that `except` block - there is probably some error happening but you're missing it since you're ignoring errors

Comment: each line in the file becomes a json object when I'm using the for loop

Comment: Post your whole file please.

Comment: the error that occurs is showing as missing delimiter ' , ' but it is the last line of the first json object

Comment: The whole file is very ill- formated  json, how do i post it ?

Comment: I have a feeling you're trying to parse a json file with a for loop. Without the whole file it's difficult to tell.

Comment: how can I send you the file ?

Comment: pastebin perhaps

Comment: alright will do it

Comment: /it is a tiny 3mb file, is there any  other way I can share it to you

Comment: I cant paste more than 512 kb file in there @DroidX86

Comment: Just try loading the file as a complete json file. https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-json-to-a-file-in-python/ I doubt you need to do json parsing for each line.

Comment: In the end I have to parse a 11 gb file so I need to do it line by line

Comment: No. If you have a 11gb json file you still should be parsing the whole thing. You do realize that one line in a JSON file might not be proper json right?

Comment: The line object in

`for line in f:`

becomes one complete json object
and I get an error of delimiter after the end of first line